# How can I use Objects form main in any class? C++

Tags: c++, window, sfml

Can anyone tell me how I can use object that I defined in main like this

```
int main()
{
sf::RenderWindow window;
}
```

And now I want to use `window` object in class that I made. But it must point out to the same `main`'s `window`. How can we use it? Can anyone explain it with some code example?
I am using SFML library of C++.

Comment: Time to read a good C++ book:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass them as references or pointers, ex.:

```
class CEngine {
  sf::RenderWindow& window;
public:
  CEngine(sf::RenderWindow& wnd) : window(wnd) {}
  // ...
};

int main()
{
sf::RenderWindow window;
CEngine engine(window);
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain 4th line of your code? Under `public` ?

Comment: This is constructor, with parameter of type reference to `sf::RenderWindow`. If you have reference field (variable) in your class you must initialize it in constructor initialization list, that is `window(wnd)`.

Comment: Why did you make constructor in private. Why not public?

Comment: It is in public, everything below `public:` is public.

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't see!

Comment: Well Thanks! I got it!

Answer (score 1):

There are several solutions to making objects created in `main` available to other code:

- Pass the `window` as a parameter, by pointer or by reference, to code that needs to use it
- Make a *singleton* object that holds a pointer to the `window`, use that object throughout your code, and set its pointer in `main` before calling any other code
- For the sake of completeness, you can make a global variable pointing to your object in `main`. This is not a good recommendation.